# Bouml - Code Generation

Tags: uml, software-design

It might be obvious (at least not for me), but I am incapable of generating my 
C++ code from UML with Bouml 4.23. So far i used the menu item "generate C++" and it always reports that it is "done" but it seems that I can't locate the files, or there are no files as the report doesn't state anything else than being done.

Comment: Does your classes have an asociated artifact? You can check it in the Class Dialog.

Comment: what is that artifact?

Comment: Read the doc for full description, it's like an abstraction for a file.  http://www.bouml.fr/doc/artifact.html

Comment: now i get it. it seems that i did that thing before, but instead of associating only one class, i associated all classes with one artifact. Isn't there a way to generate all the artifacts automatically?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associate your classes with artifacts, and then you would be able to generate code.

Check in "Class Dialog".